# Video upload stuck in processing in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, video

I am trying to upload a video trailer for my new game and when I hitted "save" I got a message on the video saying "Processing app preview - The app preview can take up to 24 hours to process." https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4047131/10/2016-10-13_181501.png

However it has taken well over 100 hours and this is still showing like this. How long does it take or is there something more I have to do to finish the video processing? Have anyone else got this problem?

These are the video specs/details: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4047131/11/2016-10-18_124815.png

Comment: its may be your video format is wrong please check properly.

Comment: like that these all things is right

 vid bitrate : 10240

frame rate: 30

audio quality: 256

Comment: These are the details, is some of them wrong? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4047131/11/2016-10-18_124815.png